# Mapstruct mapping of child classes is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I have two classes **Order** and **TargetOrder**

```
class Order {
   Location location;
   Address address;
}
class Location{
   double lat;
   double lng;
}

class Address{
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Target Order looks something like this :

```
class TargetOrder{
   TargetAddress targetAddress;
}

class TargetAddress{
   double lat;
   double lng;
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Now I have written MapStruct mapping for Address to TargetAddress;

So, something like this:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface OrderMapper {

    @Mapping(...)
    @Mapping(...)
    TargetAddress mapAddressToTargetAddress(Address address);

    @Mapping(target = "targetAddress", source = "address")
    @Mapping(target = "targetAddress.lat", source = "location.lat")
    @Mapping(target = "targetAddress.lng", source = "location.lng")
    TargetOrder mapOrderToTargetOrder(Order order);
```

When I do this, `mapOrderToTargetOrder` implementation doesn't use existing
`mapAddressToTargetAddress`

but if I remove

```
@Mapping(target = "targetAddress.lat", source = "location.lat")
@Mapping(target = "targetAddress.lng", source = "location.lng")
```

Then mapper uses existing `mapAddressToTargetAddress`.

I want to map using existing mapping and then map location attributes as well.
I have tried using `@MappingTarget` as well it is not working.

Is there any other way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use mapStruct `@Named` annotation and specify the additional `qualifiedByName`parameter in `@Mapping` annotation.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface OrderMapper {

    @Named("mapAddressToTargetAddress")
    @Mapping(...)
    @Mapping(...)
    TargetAddress mapAddressToTargetAddress(Address address);

    @Mapping(target = "targetAddress", source = "address", qualifiedByName = "mapAddressToTargetAddress")
    @Mapping(target = "lat", source = "location.lat")
    @Mapping(target = "lng", source = "location.lng")
    TargetOrder mapOrderToTargetOrder(Order order);
}
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work either; I've also updated the question as well. Since lat lng is in TargetAddress; it's not working